# Can i do audio monitoring with wireless headphones with a field recorder?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, wireless

I am new to audio. I was wondering if I can plug in a wireless headphone system, like a cheap bluetooth audio transmiter, to the audio-out jack of a field recorder such as Tascam DR-05 or Zoom H1 when used with a lavalier mic on the subject.

I don´t need high quality sound monitoring just to make sure that the lavalier is turned on and recording.

(I am planning on leaving the recorder and lapel mic for hours on a moving subject, "run & gun" style, and I am afraid the subject will accidentaly unplug the cable, damage the mic or foul-up the recorder. I know there are wireless recorders but they are out of my price range, and I am working under the assumption that this way will yield better sound quality than a shotgun mic on camera. In case it´s relevant, my total audio budget is $200: either just a Rode Videomic Pro on camera or a Tascam DR-05+ ATR-3350 lav + cheap wireless headphones, buying either audio "solution" for now and adding the other later for more versatility)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no reason why not. You'd just have to make sure you find a transmitter that's battery powered, and small enough so you can bundle it with the micro-recorder.

The question is; is it necessary. Would you be able to do anything, such as stop the event/filming, if there was a problem? Secondly; the feed you're monitoring is only going to tell you it's listening, not recording.

We use the micro Tascams with Lav Mics for some events. My recomendation is:

- Double Up:  Two Micro Tascam Units
- Double Lav Mic Clip
- Test Test Test your settings; input levels, auto gain vs manual, bit rate, etc, and get them both setup so you wont overmodulate.
- Run one slightly cold. Lower the gain / input on 1 mic by 5 db. So if the speaker gets really loud, you have a lower gain recording.
- Record in PCM 24 Bit if possible. You can then use compression in post to get super even audio.
- Use black gaff tape to tape OVER the hold button after starting the unit. This will prevent the units from having both a button pressed, as well as the guy turning off the hold button - it's happened to me.
- When you start the recorders in the field, at the very start; talk right into the mics, and say; DATE, TIME, EVENT, PERSON THE MIC IS GOING ON, ETC.
- Then tape HOLD and LAV them up.

I'd do double mics over monitor, but not sure if that's what you want monitoring for.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. great one about dual systems and the tape, I had thought about encasing the Tascam unit in a DIY plastic box. Back ups would be ideal, but as most beginers, while understanding how critical audio is,  I already invested over 95% of my initial budget in video gear and accessories and until I earn enough from videography to justify spending more on audio i´ll have to make do will less.

Comment: A small project box is a good idea, they come in practically every size imaginable. Again, you haven't said what you're filming; so just keep in mind if this is for a recurring type of shoot; have the "bundle" be flexible. Belt clip, vs; putting it in their pocket; if it's a woman; no pockets, and dress, no where to clip... I would go for a side by side config if using the unit + another unit and/or audio transmitter. Keep it as thin and small as possible. My recommendation is a dual record setup; run one hot one cold; and a dual mic clip with two decent condenser lapel mics.

Comment: Haven´t started yet but it would be for low-budget weddings, maybe events, and YouTube videos. So, I am mostly limited to "lav" the groom, the subject, or myself. If/when I start earning from this, i´ll invest in better gear: if you think it´s really essential for good audio, then I can stretch my initial audio gear investment up to under $1000. I´ll also have two DSLR cameras recording audio, and an iPhone I can use for sound either natively or with mic. Yes their audio quality is subpar but I thought of mixing channels for some ambient sounds, speeches far from the subject, or music.